# How to put JavaScript data in URL that Gmail recognizes as URL?

Tags: javascript, url

I am encoding the view state in the hash using [rison](https://github.com/Nanonid/rison).

Here is an example URL:

```
http://example.com/board/projects#(date:'2019-01-24',projects:!(5441))
```

Here is how Gmail recognizes it:
http://example.com/board/projects#(date:'2019-01-24',projects:!(5441))

By the way, SE parser fails to recognize it properly as well:
http://example.com/board/projects#(date:'2019-01-24',projects:!(5441))

Even though all of the characters are valid URL characters, I am getting complaints from users that they can't send the link in gmail (which is actually possible, just doesn't happen automatically).

Is there any other encoding library or method that would encode the json object in the hash that would be safe for parsers such as gmail?

Comment: Can you send HTML email? Recognizing URLs in plain text is done heuristically, there's no universal standard.

Comment: @Barmar The problem is the users just copying the URL from address bar and pasting it in gmail.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand because you put the URLs in plain text, and the SO parser is messing with them. Why did you undo my edit that put them into code blocks?

Comment: The Rison documentation even mentions that email programs may have trouble with these URLs. See the section titled "Emailing URIs".

Comment: @Barmar I have now edited the question to include both the code-formatted URL as you suggested and the interpretations by parsers. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: I think most solutions involve putting delimiters around the URL, e.g. `<http://blahblah>` or `<URL:http://foobar>`. But if the users are doing the pasting by hand, there's nothing you can put in the URL to force them to do that.

Comment: I was going to suggest using a link shortener, like `tinyurl.com`. But that's only useful for putting links in text, the real URL will still show up in the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Standard [URI encoding](https://github.com/Nanonid/rison#interaction-with-uri--encoding) should do the job.

```js
const base = "http://example.com/board/projects"
const data = "(date:'2019-01-24',projects:!(5441))"
const encoded_data = encodeURIComponent(data);
const final = base + '#' + encoded_data;
console.log(final);
```

Comment: I don't think this helps. The parentheses aren't encoded, and that's probably causing email parsers to misread it.

Comment: @Barmar — The question shows the comma is the pain point and that is being encoded.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working fine in gmail. However I am not feeling safe if this won't fail in another email client/web-client. At least it's not correctly recognized by the parser on this site.